# what's the difference between float arrayName[][] and float (* arrayNamePointer)[]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

What's happening below?

The following is an excerpt from C Primer Plus:

```
const float rain[YEARS][MONTHS] =
    {
        { 4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 3.0, 2.0, 1.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 2.4, 3.5, 6.6 },
        { 8.5, 8.2, 1.2, 1.6, 2.4, 0.0, 5.2, 0.9, 0.3, 0.9, 1.4, 7.3 },
        { 9.1, 8.5, 6.7, 4.3, 2.1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 1.1, 2.3, 6.1, 8.4 },
        { 7.2, 9.9, 8.4, 3.3, 1.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.0, 0.6, 1.7, 4.3, 6.2 },
        { 7.6, 5.6, 3.8, 2.8, 3.8, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.3, 2.6, 5.2 }
    };

    int year, month;
    float subtot, total;

    printf(" YEAR RAINFALL (inches)\n");

    for (year = 0, total = 0; year < YEARS; year++)
    {
        // for each year, sum rainfall for each month
        for (month = 0, subtot = 0; month < MONTHS; month++)
        {
            subtot += rain[year][month];
        }

        printf("%5d %15.1f\n", 2010 + year, subtot);
        total += subtot; // total for all years
    }
```

I had to change this to use pointers instead of the array subscripts.

So I went with:

```
[....]

float (* rainPointer)[2];
rainPointer = rain;

[....]

subtot += *(*(rainPointer + year) + month);
```

This works for year 0. The year increments correctly and the month resets correctly. However, year 1 isn't pointing where I'd expect it to. I've stepped through this a million times, I've run them side by side, rainPointer always (to my eyes) seems correct, year and month are always correct.

I found the answer via google, I should be using:

```
subtot += *(*(rain + year) + month);
```

what's the different between rain and rainPointer? Why are they not the same, if they both pointer to the beginning of an array of two ints?

Something is happening that I'm obviously not aware of, or completely missing.

Comment: Is it a typo that `rainPointer` is declared with an innermost array dimension of `[2]` rather than `[12]` (or `[MONTHS]`)?

Comment: not that I'm aware of? I could be misunderstanding, but as far as the book states (and that snippet is verbatim) you have to declare a pointer to an array that has to point to the start of an array with two ints? I'm not explaining that well.

Comment: `int`s don't appear to be involved; both `rain` and `rainPointer` concern arrays of `float`s. The thing is: `rain` is an array of arrays of 12 `float`s each, and `rainPointer` is a pointer to arrays of 2 `float`s each. They're not exactly compatible, and you'd only do this if you wanted to access the data as though it were in a differently layed out 2D array (and cared nothing about strict aliasing rules). And if you wanted to do that, then it sounds as though you got the expected behavior.

Comment: yeah my bad, I misread you, replace int/float with T I guess. I was meant to say the following (from the book): 
`Hence,pz must point to an array of two ints, not to a single int. Here is what you can do:

int (* pz)[2]; // pz points to an array of 2 ints` pz in this case would be rain, or as I thought, rainPointer.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, and you could use that declaration if you wanted to point into an `int foo[N][2]`. As it is, you want to point into a `float foo[N][12]`, so you need a `float (*rainPointer)[12]`. (Or the same with `MONTHS` instead of `12`. I assume `MONTHS` is `12`.)

Comment: okay, that makes sense. I obviously misunderstood the book. I added the 12 and it works as it should, thanks for that. Although the answer seemed to suggest I didn't need rainPointer anyway as rain does the job on its own.

Comment: Well, yes, sort of. Arrays decay to pointers to their first element at the drop of a hat (very nearly whenever you use them), so you get the same pointer implicitly without giving it a name. By the way, this also happens if you write `rain[0][1]`, since `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)`, and consequently `a[i][j]` as `*(*(a + i) + j)`. Array access is pointer arithmetic, which is probably more surprising than it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rain is a two-dimensional array declared like

```
const float rain[YEARS][MONTHS];
```

In expressions the name of an array is converted to pointer to the first element of the array. For example if you have an array

```
T rain[YEARS];
```

then in expression `rain` is converted to pointer of type `T *`

In fact a two-dimensional array is a one-dimensional array elements of which in turn one-dimensional arrays.

Thus declaration

```
const float rain[YEARS][MONTHS];
```

can be written like

```
typedef float T[MONTHS];
const T rain[YEARS];
```

where T has type `float [MONTHS}`

So as `rain` is converted to pointer to its first element that is to pointer to its first row then due to the pointer arithmetic expression `rain + year` is pointer that points to the one-dimensional array (row) that corresponds to this year.

Expression *(rain + year) yields this array that is this row.

So *(rain + year) is some row that is a one-dimensional array. Again the array is converted to pointer to its first element. The type of the element is `const float` Thus expression `*(rain + year) + month` is a pointer to the element in this one-dimensional array (row) that corresponds to the given month.

At last expression `*(*(rain + year) + month)` yields this element of the row.

So using expression `rain + year`you iterate through rows. Using expression `*(rain + year) + month` you iterates through elements of the given row
.

If you want to rewrite the loops using only pointers then they can look like

```
const float ( *rain_ptr )[MONTHS];
const float *month_ptr;
float total = 0.0f;

for ( rain_ptr = rain; rain_ptr != rain + YEARS; ++rain_ptr )
{
    // for each year, sum rainfall for each month
    float subtot = 0.0f;
    for ( month_ptr = *rain_ptr; month_ptr != *rain_ptr + MONTHS; ++month_ptr )
    {
        subtot += *month_ptr;
    }

    printf("%5d %15.1f\n", 2010 + rain_ptr - rain, subtot);
    total += subtot; // total for all years
}
```

Of course if the compiler allows then there is no any need to declare the pointers before the loops. It is better to declare them in the loop statements.

Comment: thanks. I think I'm understanding this for the most part, I do grasp how array names decay into pointers, I see why my attempted method isn't needed (why point to start of an array with rainPointer when I can just use rain itself instead), I couldn't grasp why using rainPointer and doing the same arithmetic gave different results.

Comment: @Scotty Smiles Could you show an example that gives different results? By the way you may ask me a question in English in my personal forum in the section for beginners (the first section) at www.cpp.forum24.ru

Comment: @Scotty Smiles See my answer to your question personally to me.:)